# Question About Cauchy Product;

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, generating-functions, cauchy-product

Is there a formula to multiply many series (More than two) using the Cauchy product?

If there isn't, please tell me how I can write this formula $ \left( \frac{1}{a-e^x} \right) ^{n+1}$as the bellow form $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_{n,m}\frac{x^m}{m!}$, where $c_{n,m}$ it's a serie.

And thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula to multiply finitely many series:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Generalizations